# Visualizing spherical harmonics in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to draw a spherical harmonics for my college project. The following formula I want to depict,

```
Y = cos(theta)
```

for that, I wrote this code

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sph2cart(r, phi, tta):
   ''' r is from 0 to infinity '''
   ''' phi is from 0 to 2*pi '''
   ''' tta is from 0 to pi '''
   x = r* np.sin(tta)* np.cos(phi)
   y = r* np.sin(tta)* np.sin(phi)
   z = r* np.cos(tta)
   return x, y, z

# phi running from 0 to pi and tta from 0 to pi
phi = np.linspace(0, 2* np.pi, 25)
tta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 25)
# meshgrid to generate points
phi, tta = np.meshgrid(phi, tta)

# THIS IS THE FUNCTION
Y = np.cos(tta)
# finally all things in cartesian co-ordinate system
# Note that "Y" is acting as "r"
x, y, z = sph2cart( Y, phi, tta)

# plotting :-
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 111 , projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, linewidth = 0.5, edgecolors = 'k')
```

And, get the sphere as a result. Which is not correct, because actual result is dumbbell like shape. See the second row of this image,

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Spherical_Harmonics.png/1024px-Spherical_Harmonics.png

Comment: It is not a sphere, it is a spheroid, if you want to see the real proportion use `plt.axis("equal")`, that equation is just one of the lobes.

Comment: I also found [this page](http://www.magben.de/?h1=mathematik_fuer_ingenieure_mit_python&h2=kugelflaechenfunktionen) which plots some nice spherical harmonics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picture in the Wikipedia article [Spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) is obtained by using the *absolute value* of a spherical harmonic as the r coordinate, and then coloring the surface according to the sign of the harmonic. Here is an approximation.

```
x, y, z = sph2cart(np.abs(Y), phi, tta)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 111 , projection='3d')

from matplotlib import cm
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, linewidth = 0.5, facecolors = cm.jet(Y), edgecolors = 'k')
```

[image: dumbbell]

When you use Y itself as r, the two hemispheres (positive Y and negative Y) end up mapped onto the same half of the above surface.

Answer (score 0):

The Y you are passing to the function needs to be an absolute value to make it r, else z = cos(theta)^2 is always positive. If r is to be the radius then this what you should be doing.

```
x, y, z = sph2cart(np.abs(Y), phi, tta)
```